# mysqld: unrecognized service

Tags: mysql, redhat

I'm trying to install a MySql Server on Red Hat Linux.

I've downloaded the `tar` file and unarchived it.

Then, I ran:

`rpm -qpl mysql-community-server-5.7.17-1.e16.x86_64.rpm`

Then I tried running

`service mysqld start`

But I'm getting `mysqld: unrecognized service`

I also tried using the full path to the `mysqld`: `service /usr/sbin/mysqld/ start` but that shows the same issue.

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

on my Ubuntu platform, I encountered the same problem showing "mysqld: unrecognized service".

to solve this error, the commend should be:

```sh
sudo service mysql start
```